# Zoom HTML/CSS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I want to try out the zoom effect on click of an element as similar to this link https://codepen.io/soniajain/full/QBejVL/

what I have tried is this https://codepen.io/soniajain/pen/dqXZxg but unable to do the correct calculation.

It would be great if anyone could help me with this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.zoomTarget').click(function () {

            centerSelected();

       });
    });


function centerSelected() {


    var ele = $('.zoomTarget');
    var offset = ele.offset();
    var offsetLeft = offset.left;
    var offsetTop = offset.top;
    var vw = $(window).width();
    var vh = $(window).height();
    var scale = 2;

    $('.wrapper').css({});


}



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and  the working example is as follows:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b1169cb27

In this solution I have added `transition` for the animation (to achieve smooth zooming) and `transform` to achieve zooming in the css. Now To get the "zoom target" into focus I have written following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
        position = wrapper.offset();
   $('.zoomTarget').click(function (e) {
            wrapper.toggleClass("wrapperzoom");
        var lx = e.currentTarget.offsetLeft,
        ly = e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
        if(wrapper.hasClass("wrapperzoom")){
            //where 3 represent the amount of scaling value used in css
            wrapper.offset({ top: (position.top - ly)*3, left: (position.left - lx)*3});
        }else{
            wrapper.css({ top: "auto", left: "auto"});
        }

   });
});
```

Comment: There is some disturbance in this code. when I am clicking it gets to top and than gets in center which should not be the case

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following code on onclick for zoom in :

```js
$("#imgID").css({
      'width' : $("#img01").width()  * 1.1
    , 'height': $("#img01").height() * 1.1
  });
```

Use the following code on onclick zoom out:

```js
 $("#imgID").css({
      'width' : $("#img01").width()  * 0.9
    , 'height': $("#img01").height() * 0.9
  });
```